# PHP convert multi dimensional array into single dimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays

Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 11,
            [Create_date] => 2017-11-23
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10,
            [Create_date] => 2017-11-23
        ),

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 9,
            [Create_date] => 2017-11-23
        ),

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8,
            [Create_date] => 2017-11-23
        ),

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7,
            [Create_date] => 2017-11-23
        )

);
```

Expected Array:

```
array('11','10','9','8', '7');
```

I know How can I achieve this result by using a loop but for performance improvement, we want to use inbuilt function can anyone please tell us How can we achieve this result?

Comment: For your case nothing is better than `array_column(inputarray, key)` you must use it

Answer (score 4):

### Simple use [array_column() Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) in php

```
$array = [

[
    "ID" => 11,
    "Create_date" => "2017-11-23"
], 
[
    "ID" => 10,
    "Create_date" => "2017-11-23"
], 
[
    "ID" => 9,
    "Create_date" => "2017-11-23"
], 
[
    "ID" => 8,
    "Create_date" => "2017-11-23"
], 
];

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_column($array, "ID"));
?>
```

Comment: Upvoted. But I suggest to link to php.net rather than w3schools :)

Answer (score 0):

Using foreach

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key.'<br/>';

    echo $value['id'].'<br/>';
    echo $value['Create_date'].'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple **array_map** function use.

```
<?php

    $movies = array(
      array(
        "id" => 11,
        "Create_date" => 2017-11-23,

      ),
      array(
        "id" => 10,
        "Create_date" => 2017-11-23,

      ),
      array(
         "id" => 9,
        "Create_date" => 2017-11-23,

      ),
        array(
         "id" => 8,
        "Create_date" => 2017-11-23,

      ),
       array(
         "id" => 7,
        "Create_date" => 2017-11-23,

      )
    );

    $oneDimensionalArray = array_map('current', $movies);
    print_r($oneDimensionalArray);
    ?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 10 [2] => 9 [3] => 8 [4] => 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
[
    "ID" => 11,
    "Create_date" => "2017-11-23"
], 
[
    "ID" => 10,
    "Create_date" => "2017-11-23"
], 
[
    "ID" => 9,
    "Create_date" => "2017-11-23"
], 
[
    "ID" => 8,
    "Create_date" => "2017-11-23"
], 
];

foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{    
    $id[]          =  $value['id'];
    $creatteDate[] = $value['Create_date'];
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($creatteDate); 

print_r($id); 

exit;
```